# Intro to programming project. Stuck on creating a data file from a table

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been given a project for class and am stuck on a part of it.  The project has this table in it:

[image]

How can I create this information into a sequential file to read into a C++ program?  It looks like this would be a 3 dimensional array. Am I looking too far into this?

Comment: For a simple homework project, yes I'd say that an array would be the best choice. For anything more complicated or something you were doing in the "real world", you would probably want to use a database.

Comment: Seems that two dimensional is enough.

Comment: ...this is about a file, not about in-memory representation

Comment: I was looking at putting this into a 2 dimensional array but I just can't picture how to organize it.  I see 3 types of data here:  Sandwich type, ingredients and cost.  How would I go about organizing this?  Or am I picking this apart too much?  Thank you very much for helping btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do.  Typically if you are are just trying to read it in you can store it as a flat file. With flat files you typically have two common formats fixed length record or comma separate (there are other flat file formats you can implement but these are two common fomats).

In fixed length record each record is a fixed length and each field is a fixed length.
For example

```
Turkey             1.00Swiss        .30Roll           .30Condiments         .10
Pastrami           1.30Swiss        .40Roll           .30Condiments         .10
```

In comma separated language you can do it like this
    Turkey,1.00,Swiss,.30,Roll,.30,Condiment,.10

With fixed length record the con is that once specified and depending on who is the recipient of the file is your fields can never grow.  For example if your price field is five spaces you max value ever would be 99.99 and you would have a hard time ever increasing the field size because it would no longer be compatible if some other application depende on it being 5 characters. Comma separated is a little more flexible because the separator is the comma.  With comma separate you can usually have the fields grow in size because your comma is the separator.

There is another option and that is to create a ini type of what I will call Domain Specific format as an example take a look below

```
Sandwich: Turkey
Deli Slice: Turkey,1.00
Deli Slice: Swiss,.30
Bread: Roll,.30
Condiments: .30

Sandwich: Pastrami
Deli Slice: Pastrami,1.00
Deli Slice: Swiss,.40
Bread: Roll,.30
Condiments: .10
```

This format is more flexible because you can add more fields.  For example lets say you have a new sandwich called a california and it required meat cheese and also avocado.  You can extend it like this

```
Sandwich: California
Deli Slice: Turkey, 1.00
Deli Slice: American, .30
Deli Slice: Avocado, .50
Bread: Roll,.30
Condiments: .10
```

With this third format and some careful programming your new sandwich will automatically be backwards compatible.

Each of the files takes a different strategy for reading it in.  There is something called parsing and each file would have a different approach.
In the fixed length record the approach wouldnbe to read each column by character positions.
In the comma separated file you would need to tokenize each line read in in C++ you have a strtok but if you use managed C++ .net i believe you have a string.split.
With the third option you actually look for keywoards such as "Sandwich", "Deli SLice" etc and then you also have to tokenize the itmes because they

Comment: Thank you, I think this will give me the information I need.  Let me give some of this a shot and I will get back to all on this.  I think I will need to figure out how I want to read this from file now.  Thank you all for your suggestions.  I am extremely happy to be part of this wonderful community.

Answer (score 0):

There are all kinds of conventions you might use. For example,

```
Turkey
Turkey, 1.00
Swiss,  0.30
Roll,   0.30
Condiments, 0.10

Pastrami
Pastrami, 1.30
Swiss,     .40
...
```

This format would be easy enough to read: table header on a line, then ingredient/price pairs separated by a comma, then a blank line. Then it starts over again.

Comment: I was heading that way, then the 4th one, Special is there.  With it having turkey and pastrami there, does that screw things up?  Granted I don't have a full understanding on these just yet as you could probably guess.  So if I did like a case statement and the user put in T for Turkey, would I do a search for the heading turkey and read in until I hit a space?  Something like that?

Comment: Normally, we write programs like this to read in *all* the data into some kind of in-memory structure, and then we search that structure. So you might have (random example, not necessarily the best) a `Sandwich` class, which holds a `vector<pair<string, double> >` of ingredients; then you'd have a `vector<Sandwich>`. When you needed to know about turkey sandwiches, you'd search linearly through that `vector<Sandwich>` looking for a `Sandwich` whose `name` member equaled `turkey`; then you could look at the `vector` of ingredients.

Comment: I actually think I understand that.  Unfortunately we didn't get to classes so I can't use them.  For your file example above, I have a couple questions.  I have only seen 2D arrays of the same datatype so far.  Is it possible to have one with 2 different types of data in it?  Second, would parallel vectors be the right thing to use if I can't have different data types?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you know about `HashMaps`. If not, you could look it [up](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/). It would be very simple using that.

You can have one `map` having `key = String` and `value = Integer`. There will be 4 keys, "Turkey", "pastrami", "Ham" and "Special" and you can have values associated with them as `1,2,3,4`.

Then you can have 4 other `maps` each having `key = String` and `Value = float` and enter the above data. You can use the 1st map to check for the proper column and the other maps to get the cost.

You can of-course implement the above using `2D - arrays` but it would be a good experience to learn.
Good Luck!!

Comment: Thank you very much.  That sounds really interesting.  I am going to look that up and see if I can try that with my limited knowledge.  When you say this can be using a 2D array, do you mean like the one Ernest wrote up?  I was heading that way at one point like I said in my comment above.  If so then i was on the right track (sort of) just can't get over that hurdle.  The Hashmaps sound like it would really do the trick though.  The only issue I see is its something we haven't gone over in class.

Comment: HashMap is really similar yo a 2D array. It has two columns `<Key,Value>` same as a 2Darray. Just that you can retrieve items from a `HashMap` in `O(1)` time rather than traversing a 2D array. If you do not want to use a `map` just use 5 2D arrays as I suggested above. It will do the trick. But keep in mind you can use only a single primitive `String` (since its c++) here. So both your columns have to be a `String`. Here is a simple implementation of a `map`. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/28387/